# Linking a pdf file to an android app

Tags: android, pdf

Hi I'm a newbee to android programming. Is there a way to link a pdf file to an android app you are developing? Like Clicking a button or a Hyper Link will open a pdf file?

Comment: yes, you can have an app open a web browser and point that browser at a link which ends up sending out a pdf.

Comment: Is there any other way than linking it to a web browser? Like a saved pdf in your computer then you will load it? It will be hassle to update if the link changes or updates something. The app will crash

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and pass url of a pdf to show.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

// load the pdf.
String pdf = 'http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf';
webview.loadUrl('http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&amp;url=' + pdf);
```

Comment: It will be hassle to update if the link changes or updates something. The app will crash.

Comment: App will not crash, but becomes useless.